# How is this lamda function beeing executed in an example for the Y combinator

Tags: lambda-calculus, functional-programming

I have spent a few hours now trying to understand how the Y Combinator is working and how it allows us to construct recursive functions with higher order functions.

I have been going through this derivation http://mvanier.livejournal.com/2897.html which is using the factorial function for explanation which I find quite helpful but at some point I am always getting lost.

I still understand this part

```
  (define (part-factorial self)
    ((lambda (f)
       (lambda (n)
         (if (= n 0)
             1
             (* n (f (- n 1))))))
     (self self)))

  (define factorial (part-factorial part-factorial))
  (factorial 5) ==> 120
```

We have a function `part-factorial` which takes as a formal parameter `self` and applies it as argument `(self self)` to the first lambda function. So inside the first lambda `f` will evaluate to `(self self)` which in case of the `factorial` function will evaluate to (part-factorial, part-factorial). So in the second lambda then if we take 5 as our n the call to the function f will evaluate to `part-factorial part-factorial 4` which will start the recursion.

After a few syntax changes we now define the functions as

```
  (define almost-factorial
    (lambda (f)
      (lambda (n)
        (if (= n 0)
            1
            (* n (f (- n 1)))))))

  (define factorial
    ((lambda (x) (x x))
     (lambda (self) 
       (almost-factorial (self self)))))

  (factorial 5) ==> 120
```

And at this point I am confused. I understand the almost-factorial function as it is pretty much unchanged compared to `part-factorial` however the new factorial function is unclear to me, from a syntax perspective. I don't understand anymore which lamda will be executed with which parameters and in which order.

Could anybody explain to me the execution of this function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am just going to write `h` for `almost-factorial` because long names can sometimes obscure math.

We consider:

```
((lambda (x) (x x))
 (lambda (self) 
   (h (self self))))
```

Write `foo` for `((lambda (x) (x x))` and write `bar` for `(lambda (self) (h (self self))))`. Then our expression is just

```
(foo bar)
```

Using the definition of `foo` we see that this is equal to

```
(bar bar)
```

Then we use the definition of `bar` on the first occurrence of `bar` to see that this is equal to

```
((lambda (self) (h (self self)))) bar)
```

which in turn is just

```
(h (bar bar))
```

We discovered that `(bar bar)` is equal to `(h (bar bar))`. Let us write `g` for `(bar bar)`, so `g` is equal to `(h g)`. Taking into account the definition of `h` (which is jsut `almost-factorial` from your question) we see that `(h g)`, and therefore `g`, is equal to

```
(lambda (n)
  (if (= n 0)
      1
      (* n (g (- n 1)))))
```

In other words, `g` is the usual factorial function. I hope I got all the silly lisp parentheses where they are supposed to be.